# Google Maps - Remove Address

Tags: google-maps

How can I remove an address from Google Maps? I need to remove one address from this map. http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=en&msa=0&msid=113613286687180879498.000483d36f7130c3c3b5b&ll=29.734156,-95.30172&spn=0.003261,0.00456&z=17&source=embed

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy google search...try starting there next time.
http://www.ehow.com/how_6561194_remove-markers-google-maps.html

Comment: I don't see Edit button at all, that's why I posted the question here.

Comment: Only the creator of the map can see the edit button so no one opening your map will be able to see it either.  Make sure you are logged in using the correct account to see if this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do:

1. If you own the business: Create a local business center account and own the listing. From there you can manage updates. https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=lbc&continue=https://www.google.com/local/add%3Fservice%3Dlbc
2. If you're talking about removing the listing on a Maps API implementation you can use Styled Maps to remove the business from the map.